# how to compare only time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I want to compare only time on client side, means the start time should not be greater than end time. I have searched on net but not able resolve this problem. Please help me as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you compute start time and end time?

Comment: jquery date-picker that picks only time. i have customized it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can compare date in javascript
check following code

```
var x=new Date();
x.setFullYear(2100,0,14);
var today = new Date();

if (x>today)
{
  alert("Today is before 14th January 2100");
}
else
{
  alert("Today is after 14th January 2100");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example lets say the time picked for example

```
var startTime = "09:15";
var endTime ="10:15";

if(parseInt(startTime.split(":")[0],10) > parseInt(endTime.split(":")[0],10))
alert("Start Time should not be greater than end time");
else
alert("Valid Time");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the Date object functions to pull out the hours minutes and seconds to get just the time from a Date:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var hours = currentDate.getHours();
var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
var seconds = currentDate.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) you can use the following method [compareTo](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#compareTo)

```
var past = Date.today().add(-6).days();
var future = Date.today().add(6).days();

Date.today().compareTo(future);                 // -1
Date.today().compareTo(new Date().clearTime()); // 0
Date.today().compareTo(past);                   // 1
```

if you do not want to use a whole library here is the source code for the static `compare` method in DateJS

```
Date.compare = function (date1, date2) {
    if (isNaN(date1) || isNaN(date2)) { 
        throw new Error(date1 + " - " + date2); 
    } else if (date1 instanceof Date && date2 instanceof Date) {
        return (date1 < date2) ? -1 : (date1 > date2) ? 1 : 0;
    } else { 
        throw new TypeError(date1 + " - " + date2); 
    }
};
```

This will work for time as well asuming that both dates (yyyy-MM-dd) are the same